# Plotting every image from a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot every image I have in my folder along with their filenames as headers, but I can't seem to do it.

I've tried this this code, but the file names are all the same (they are the all the name of the final image in the list, due to the iteration problem).

```
# Put all images in the folder into a list (works)
images = []
for f in glob.iglob("/content/testing_data/Bad/*"):
    images.append(np.asarray(Image.open(f)))

# plot the images (works)
images = np.array(images)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(15, 5, figsize=(10, 50))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .3, wspace=.3)
axs = axs.ravel()

# This is for displaying the names (works)
for filename in os.listdir('/content/testing_data/Bad/'):
  RatName = filename[:-4]

# show the filename (this bit doesn't work)
for i in range(len(images)):
  axs[i].imshow(images[i])
  axs[i].set_title(RatName)
```

I want it to plot the images as subplots with the filenames as its title...

filename1, filename2, filename 3

but I get this:

filename3, filename3, filename3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are using a fixed variable as your filename. While you failed to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I believe this should work for you. The idea is to use the index `i` to set the filenames dynamically. `i+1` is used because in python, the `range(len(images))` will generate numbers starting from 0 by default

```
for i in range(len(images)):
  axs[i].imshow(images[i])
  axs[i].set_title('filename%s' %(i+1))
```

**EDIT** Try the following

```
i = 0
for filename in os.listdir('/content/testing_data/Bad/'):
  RatName = filename[:-4]
  axs[i].imshow(images[i])
  axs[i].set_title(RatName)
  i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. It's my fault for not being clear. I would like it to display the actual filenames of the images from the folder.

Comment: @MichaelManfield: You have to explain it to me what is contained in `filename[:-4]`. Does it contain the filenames you want to display? If you don't explain well, it's hard to help. Is the length of `filename[:-4]` equal to the `len(images)` ?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes you're right, filename[:-4] is the filename (shortened to the first 4 characters). I was thinking maybe creating a dictionary with image as the value, and the filename as the key... would that be easier?

Comment: @MichaelManfield: Is len(images) equal to the number of files in your directory?